# Horizontal smartphone stand wanted

Tags: smartphones

I want to use my smartphone's video function, e.g. for recording videos and for making video calls. But I do not want to hold the smartphone in my hand. Is there a good stand that holds the smartphone horizontally? The charging stations usually hold the smartphone vertically which I do not want for recording video. Nice would be a stand not only for one type of phone but for most of the phones.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy some kind of mount, eg. Joby GripTight Mount (dunno how good quality wise is this particular model is, but it's good enough for the reference) and use it with any standard camera tripod.

Or you can check out some those flexible GorillaPods (it looks like little octopuses). Many times they are sold with similar mounts as the one above. The problem with these is, they degrade fast, but on the other hand, they are quite cheap and you can attach it to a lot of other things

You can also buy little tripods. While they last longer, they lack the ability to attach themselves to various objects.

In the end you got to chose what to use

Comment: The [Joby JB01389-BWW GripTight Mount PRO](https://www.amazon.de/Joby-JB01389-BWW-GripTight-Mount-PRO/dp/B01C7UYBAA?SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-ffab-de-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01C7UYBAA) looks promising.